# Springboot/Spring Batch load a file without separator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

With Springboot/Spring Batch, I try to load a file without separator.

File Example :

```
field1field2field3
field1field2field3
field1field2field3
```

This is my code :

```
@Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {

          
          return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>() 
                  .name("personItemReader")
                  .resource(new ClassPathResource("people.txt"))
                  .lineTokenizer(new FixedLengthTokenizer()  {{ setNames("firstName", "lastName"); setColumns(new Range(1-6,7-12)); }})
                  .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{ setTargetType(Person.class); }})
                  .build()
                  ; 
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I have the following error and I don't understand why :

```
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader]: Factory method 'reader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Min value must be higher than zero
```

Can you explain me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declaration of the line tokenizer is incorrect here:

```
.lineTokenizer(new FixedLengthTokenizer() {{
      setNames("firstName", "lastName");
      setColumns(new Range(1-6,7-12));
 }})
```

This is as if you specified a range of [-5, -5]. `setColumns` takes a varargs of `Range`s where each range should be created with `Range(min, max)`. So in your case It should be something like:

```
.lineTokenizer(new FixedLengthTokenizer()  {{
       setNames("firstName", "lastName");
       setColumns(new Range(1,6), new Range(7,12));
}})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works.

I was wrong because I didn't understood the documentation about "setColumns" :
"Set the column ranges. Used in conjunction with the this property can be set in the form of a String describing the range boundaries, e.g. "1,4,7" or "1-3,4-6,7" or "1-2,4-5,7-10"."